# Media query file doesn't work even if the files are placed properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

My media query file doesn't work even if the files are placed properly.
What's going wrong? Is it because of Bootstrap?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="css/mq.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Bootstrap Style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Reset Style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <!-- Main Style -->
    <!--Font Awesome-->
    <script src="js/animatie.js"></script>
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.downCount.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css.css">
</head>
```

`mq.css` is the file for media queries:

```css
@media screen and (width: 1920px) {
    h1 {
        font-size: 222vw;
    }

    .fa-social {
        height: 1.7vw;
        width: 1.7vw;
    }

    body {
        background-color: white;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you including a normalize CSS file after your bootstrap file?  I would think that would damage a lot of the styles.

Comment: That media query works only at an *exact width* of 1920px. Is that the intended function?

Comment: Actually now that I think about it, that normalize file will very likely cause you problems.  If I recall correctly media queries do not raise specificity in CSS rules.  That means that if your normalize style sheet sets the font size of the `h1`s, for instance, it'll override your `mq.css` rule despite it being in a media query.  You should always include a normalize.css file first before any other stylesheets. CSS stylesheets cascade.

Comment: @showdev yes, I'm just testing it on a 1920px.

Comment: @JosephMarikle nothing changed. I put normalize.css first, still doesn't work.

Comment: Not a solution but a suggestion - this seems awfully bad - <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css.css">... you should perhaps name the CSS file  as something more descriptive- just for readability sake. Obviously its fine and is usable, but just reads poorly.

Comment: Is it possible to put together a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help demonstrate the problem? Or, as a last resort, can you provide a link to the page?

Comment: @AndreiDaniel You are testing at a strict width of 1920px... Do you have a scrollbar ?
 Also, I would place your mq.css after bootstrap.css (just before or just after your main style)

Comment: If you inspect the page - you will be able to see the dimensions - it is possible that if you have a scrollbar that is not part of the viewport and so the media quey is not being met and therefore not firing - (just because the sceen is 1920px does not mean that the viewport is the same width) also do you intend the h1 - to be "font-size: 222vw;" - that seems awfully big. and so that you can definitely say the media query has the last word on styles - i would put it last in the list of CSS files.

Comment: @showdev www.octaniculescu.com. I've first tried to do 1024px and it didn't work, so I've tried with 1920px. I don't really know what is going on guys

Comment: @gavgrif i know that 222vw means a lot, I just wanted to see that it works. 222vw is very noticeable I think, haha.

Comment: @AndreiDaniel If you look at your inspector tool, your mq is working... but it's overwritten by bootstrap.css, then, normalize.css, then css.css .... load your mq last and you'll see the difference

Comment: @showdev , exactly https://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/56471735mq.png

Comment: Fonts at a font size of 4262px are not really very noticeable. You will hardly see anything. Maybe a rectangular bar covering half the screen, at least if the h1's top margin is reset to 0. Otherwise, nothing.